# How to get values from rows on one table to column of other

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two tables which looks like :

**First table**

```
   CustomerId    CustomerName

    110             XYZ                 
    111             ABC
    112             PQR 
    113             LMN
```

Second Table

```
    CustomerId         PhoneNumber

      110             9823983298329 
      111             9996709760760
      110             0495054905495  
      112             8394893489843
      113             0932023090900  
      111             0930290909999
      113             8993293288888
      112             9828239882388
```

**What I want is a table structure similar to :**

```
  CustomerId      CustomerName      PhoneNum1             PhoneNum2

    110             XYZ             9823983298329        0495054905495  
    111             ABC             9996709760760        0930290909999
    112             PQR             8394893489843        9828239882388
    113             LMN             0932023090900        8993293288888
```

I am really stuck up with the logic here , If I Join the two tables using
**inner join** then output table will have **multiple CustomerId's** which is not required here , any help will be highly appreciable.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Start by taking a look at [**`ALTER TABLE`**](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/alter_table.php) and [**`INSERT INTO`**](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php).

Comment: can't I do this without making any new table?

Comment: Do you want just the result to look like this? Or the actual table?

Comment: What's the expected result if a customer has 3 different phone numbers?

Comment: ignore the third one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a form of pivot; you just need a column to pivot on.  You can get this result using conditional aggregation and `row_number()`:

```
select t1.CustomerId, t1.CustomerName,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then PhoneNmber end) as PhoneNmber1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then PhoneNmber end) as PhoneNmber2
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customerId order by customerId) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.CustomerId = t2.CustomerId
group by t1.CustomerId, t1.CustomerName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `GROUP BY` to find each customer's min and max phone no. Do a `LEFT JOIN` with that result:

```
select f.CustomerId,
       f.CustomerName,
       s.min_ph,
       case when s.min_ph <> s.max_ph then s.max_ph else null end
from firsttable f
  left join (select CustomerId,
                    min(PhoneNumber) min_ph,
                    max(PhoneNumber) max_ph 
             from secondtable
             group by CustomerId) s on f.CustomerId = s.CustomerId
```

Answer (score 0):

With use analytic function lead

```
select max(CustomerId),max(PhoneNUmber),max(PhoneNUmber2),max(PhoneNUmber3) from (
 select a.CustomerId,PhoneNUmber ,lead(phonenumber,1) over(partition by  a.CustomerId order by phonenumber) PhoneNUmber2,lag(phonenumber,2) over(partition by a.CustomerId order by phonenumber) PhoneNUmber3  from firsttable a
   join secoundTable b on a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId
   order by 1
)
group by CustomerId;
```